# How To Populate Table With Filtered Data in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I am attempting to populate a table with a filtered set of data from my Manifests model using a url parameter.

I believe that the problem I am having is in the Views.py line

```
 manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference_id)
```

Models.py

```
class Manifests(models.Model):

    reference = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
    cases = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^add_manifest/(?P<reference_id>\d+)/$', add_manifest, name='add_manifest'),
```

Views.py

```
def add_manifest(request, reference_id):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                order = Orders.objects.get(id=reference_id)
            except Orders.DoesNotExist:
                pass  
            instance.reference = order
            instance.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest', reference_id=reference_id)

    form = CreateManifestForm()
    #manifests = Manifests.objects.all()
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference_id)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'reference_id': reference_id,
        'manifests' : manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

template (add_manifest.html)

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

  <div class="container">
    <form method="POST">

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.reference">Reference ID: </label><br>
          <input type="text" value="{{ reference_id }}">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.description">Description: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.description}}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.cases">Cases: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.cases }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.count">Count: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.count }}
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
          <br>
          <br>


      <button type="submit" name="add_mani" style="border-color: #7395AE;">Add Line</button>
    </form>


    <br>
    <h4>Manifest</h4>

    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered manifest_table" cellspacing="0" style="width="100%">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Ref ID</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Cases</th>
          <th style="width:60%;">Description</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Count</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        {% for manifests in manifests %}

        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_manifest_browse' manifests.pk %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ manifests.reference }}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.cases }}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.description}}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.count}}</td>
        </tr>

        {% endfor %}

      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" align="right">Subit Manifest</button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

I want the table to display only lines where the reference in the Manifests model = the reference_id in the URL.  Currently it does not work as such, the table is just empty.

Comment: The form you submit is `POST` or `GET` request? and what is the output if this     `manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference_id)` just print `manifests` to see it has value or not. Also, print `reference_id` to see which value it pass as url parameter.

Comment: @shafik the form I submit is POST request. and I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about the output.  If you look at the .html file, I am rendering a table using the 'manifests' variable.  I would like for that table to fill with filtered data where the reference field in the Manifests model is equal to the reference ID in the URL. so the output is for the table to fill with that data only as opposed to all records in the Manifests model.

Comment: Try using GET instead of POST. Because POST request only execute this portion code `if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                order = Orders.objects.get(id=reference_id)
            except Orders.DoesNotExist:
                pass  
            instance.reference = order
            instance.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest', reference_id=reference_id)`

Comment: @shafik are you able to provide me an example of what you are suggesting? I can post any code you might need - I am very new to Django and am finding myself confused.

Comment: Add the html form by which you pass `reference_id` value

Comment: @shafik I edited the original post to show the entirety of the HTML file thank you

Comment: Change this `<form method="POST">` to `<form method="GET">`.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the for-loop variable name like this:

```
{% for manifest in manifests %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="{% url 'edit_manifest_browse' manifests.pk %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ manifest.reference }}</td>
      <td>{{ manifest.cases }}</td>
      <td>{{ manifest.description}}</td>
      <td>{{ manifest.count}}</td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

If there is any `Manifest` object for `reference_id`, then it will render them in template.

#### Update

Its possible that your form is not validating. So its a good idea to render form errors:

```
# view
def add_manifest(request, reference_id):
    form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                order = Orders.objects.get(id=reference_id)
                instance.reference = order
            except Orders.DoesNotExist:
                pass  
            instance.save()
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference_id)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'reference_id': reference_id,
        'manifests' : manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

And update template to show the errors in template as well:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div>
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div>
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you for the response - perhaps I need to clarify my initial post as this still returns nothing. When I render this form - no data will be in the table, as no data will have been created for this order yet. One line of Manifest data is entered, submitted, and then the user is being redirected to the same form again at the same URL. I can see that my data is posting to the model, but the table still comes up blank each time I refresh that form.

Comment: I think your form might not be validating. I have updated the answer @GXM100 please have a look

Comment: but if I can see the data that I am entering here in the model when I go to the admin then the form must be validating, right? Because this is the case for me at the moment

Comment: can you check the reference id is correct or not. Because if reference id does not exist in DB, it will show empty Manifests

Comment: ahh reference_id was correct but that pointed me in the right direction - instead of  using  manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference_id) I needed to first set reference_id = to something, as it seemingly is not pulling it from the URL parameter in this case.  But I have it working now. Thanks @ruddra